# labeling points on the circle with the same symbol

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-pic

I am trying to draw a circle centered at A(1,1) and radius 1. I also want to draw 2 dashed lines from center to the points B(1,0) and C(0,1). here is my progress

```
\begin{tikzpicture} 
  \tkzInit[xmin=-1, xmax=2.5, ymin=-1, ymax=2.5]
  \tkzDrawXY[noticks,label={}]
  \tkzDefPoint(1,1){A} 
  \tkzDefPoint(1,0){1}
  \tkzDefPoint(0,1){1} 
  \tkzLabelPoints[below](1)
  \tkzLabelPoints[left](1) 
  \draw[fill=gray!20] (1,1) circle (1cm);
  \tkzDrawPoints[fill=black,size=10](A,B,C) 
  \draw [dashed] (A) -- (1),
  \draw [dashed] (A) -- (1), 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I would like to label B and C as "1", but this way, the only points draw is the origin, which I don't understand why, and C which has two labels 1, one left and other below. Can anyone help me, please?

After the hints that a received here, here is the result:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
 \tkzInit[xmin=-1, xmax=2.5, ymin=-1, ymax=2.5]
 \tkzDrawXY[noticks,label={}]
 \tkzDefPoint(1,1){A} 
 \tkzDefPoint(1,0){B}
 \tkzDefPoint(0,1){C} 
 \path (A) node[above right] {$A$} (B) node[below] {1} (C) node[left]{1};
%  \tkzLabelPoints[above right](A)
%  \tkzLabelPoints[below](B)
%  \tkzLabelPoints[left](C) 
 \draw(A) circle[radius=1cm];
 \tkzDrawPoints[fill=black,size=2](A,B,C) 
 \draw [dashed] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW, I have no idea how you formatted your code in the question (which is why I did not fix it), but in the future please kindly consider putting it in the cursor and pressing the `{}` button.

Or

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
 \tkzInit[xmin=-1, xmax=2.5, ymin=-1, ymax=2.5]
 \tkzDrawXY[noticks,label={}]
 \tkzDefPoint(1,1){A} 
 \tkzDefPoint(1,0){B}
 \tkzDefPoint(0,1){C} 
 \path %(A) node[above right] {$A$} 
 (B) node[below] {1} (C) node[left]{1};
%  \tkzLabelPoints[above right](A)
%  \tkzLabelPoints[below](B)
%  \tkzLabelPoints[left](C) 
 \draw(A) circle[radius=1cm];
 \tkzDrawPoints[fill=black,size=2](A,B,C) 
 \draw [dashed] (C) -- (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Almost perfect. I don't need the label of the center and the dashed line between $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$. Could you edit you answer for me? Thanks for your help

Comment: @MarcosPaulo Sure. (I guess it would make more sense if you tried what these commands do.)

Comment: Thanks again! One more thing about what I intended to do is to fill the circle wit 20% of grey. Also, I don't understand what you mean with "consider putting it in the cursor and pressing the {} button". Finally, I must confess that I don't how to use `\usepackage{tkz-euclide}`, `\path`and `\node`commands yet.

Comment: @MarcosPaulo Then just use `\draw[fill=gray!20] (A) circle[radius=1cm];`. I recommend going in small steps. The pgfmanual has a great tutorial. After you have absorbed it, you can look at all these additional packages. Going the other way around is IMHO a bit risky.

Comment: I was to what you said, because I did `\draw(A) circle[fill=gray!20, radius=1cm];`... Yes some hints that I used came from the tikz manual (not pgf) and others from YouTube videos. These manuals are so big. I will post here my project. This picture will take part of a beamer presentation that I will convert to videos for my students. Many thanks again!